# How I can share Store to TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Here is the code I am trying to use but in the component LogIn I get an error that I have not shared the store. I try share the store to tabNavigation to have all the child components with the Store.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import TabNavigator from './TabNavigator';
import { Store } from './Store/Store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';


<Provider store={Store}>
    <TabNavigator></TabNavigator>
</Provider>

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Error:

> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in
>   the context of "Connect(LogIn)". Either wrap the root component in a
>   , or pass a custom React context provider to  and
>   the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(LogIn) in connect
>   options.

[Source Code](https://github.com/sssolammm/ReactLoginFirebase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `App.js` needs to export a `React.Component`, currently you’re exporting a navigator. You also don’t have a render function. So you’re not going to see anything. You should refactor your `App.js` so that it looks more like this.

```
import React from 'react';
Import { View } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import TabNavigator from './TabNavigator';
import { Store } from './Store/Store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const Nav = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    <Provider store={Store}>
      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
        <Nav />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  }
}
```

Here is a snack that uses redux https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/redux-with-ducks it follows the idea from https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux